# What is the idiomatic way to pop the last N elements in a mutable Vec?

Tags: rust

I am contributing Rust code to RosettaCode to both learn Rust and contribute to the Rust community at the same time. What is the best idiomatic way to pop the last *n* elements in a mutable `Vec`?

Here's roughly what I have written but I'm wanting to see if there's a better way:

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    nums.push(1);
    nums.push(2);
    nums.push(3);
    nums.push(4);
    nums.push(5);

    let n = 2;
    for _ in 0..n {
        nums.pop();
    }

    for e in nums {
        println!("{}", e)
    }
}
```

([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4961b011516314597f63ebbb9aa3abbe&version=stable&backtrace=0))

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`Vec::truncate`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate):

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    let n = 2;
    let final_length = nums.len().saturating_sub(n);
    nums.truncate(final_length);

    println!("{:?}", nums);
}
```

Additionally, I

- used [`saturating_sub`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.saturating_sub) to handle the case where there aren't `N` elements in the vector
- used [`vec![]`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.vec!.html) to construct the vector of numbers easily
- printed out the entire vector in one go

---

Normally when you "pop" something, you want to have those values. If you want the values in another vector, you can use [`Vec::split_off`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_off):

```
let tail = nums.split_off(final_length);
```

If you want access to the elements but do not want to create a whole new vector, you can use [`Vec::drain`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain):

```
for i in nums.drain(final_length..) {
    println!("{}", i)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

An alternate approach would be to use [Vec::drain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) instead. This gives you an iterator so you can actually use the elements that are removed.

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    nums.push(1);
    nums.push(2);
    nums.push(3);
    nums.push(4);
    nums.push(5);

    let n = 2;
    let new_len = nums.len() - n;

    for removed_element in nums.drain(new_len..) {
        println!("removed: {}", removed_element);
    }

    for retained_element in nums {
        println!("retained: {}", retained_element);
    }
}
```

The drain method accepts a `RangeArgument` in the form of `<start-inclusive>..<end-exclusive>`. Both start and end may be omitted to default to the beginning/end of the vector. So above, we're really just saying start at `new_len` and drain to the end.

Comment: Then how to remove some elements from a slice?

Comment: @chenzhongpu `slice_variable = &slice_variable[..new_len];`

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at the [`Vec::truncate`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.truncate) function from the standard library, that can do this for you.

([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=355db0a3ae62aed1841418ed64930f91&version=stable&backtrace=0))

```
fn main() {
    let mut nums: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
    nums.push(1);
    nums.push(2);
    nums.push(3);
    nums.push(4);
    nums.push(5);

    let n = 2;
    let new_len = nums.len() - n;
    nums.truncate(new_len);

    for e in nums {
        println!("{}", e)
    }
}
```