# What is a less verbose way to repeatedly pop() items from a vector?

Tags: stack, rust

When using a vector as a stack *(storing states which are pushed and popped)*.

```
while stack.len() != 0 {
    let state = stack.pop().unwrap();
    // ... optionally push other states onto the stack.
}
```

Is there a less verbose way to do this in Rust?

Comment: See also [What is the idiomatic way to pop the last N elements in a mutable Vec?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28952411/155423).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the fact that `pop()` returns an `Option<T>` and match on that using a `while let` loop:

```rust
while let Some(state) = stack.pop() {
    // ... fine to call stack.push() here
}
```

The `while let` desugars to something like the following:

```rust
loop {
    match stack.pop() {
        Some(state) => {
            // ... fine to call stack.push() here
        }
        _ => break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to offer an alternative approach, you can also use the [drain method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) to remove elements and give them to you in an `Iterator`.

`stack.drain(..).map(|element| ...and so on`

or

```
for element in stack.drain(..) {
    //do stuff
}
```

You can also provide a `RangeArgument` if you only want to remove a certain range of elements. This can be provided in the form of `<start-inclusive>..<end-exclusive>`. Both the start and end of the range argument are optional and just default to the start of end of the vector, so calling `drain(..)` just drains the entire vector, while `drain(2..)` would leave the first 2 elements in place and just drain the rest.

Comment: Will this work when the body of the for loop adds items to the stack though?

Comment: No, this won't work when you're also adding items to the stack because [drain](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) mutably borrows the Vec. If you need to do both, I'd recommend the `while let Some(item) = stack.pop() {...` approach described in the answer from SpaceManiac.