# What is the idiomatic way to remove the first N elements in a mutable Vec?

Tags: vector, rust

Is there a good way to remove multiple elements at the start of a vector?

I would like to avoid multiple removals which cause unnecessary memory copying operations.

```
while vec.len() > n {
    vec.remove(0);
}
```

---

1. I could use unsafe API's (`ptr::drop_in_place`, `ptr::copy`, `Vec::set_len`), but was hoping there were a more convenient way to handle this.
2. Might an alternative solution be possible where the `Vec` pointer is offset and the range at the start is marked as free? (no memory copying required). *I now realize this requires Rust's underlying allocator to free memory by range not the initially allocated pointer, but it turns out this isn't the case.*

Comment: Note that this question is quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952411 - only it asks about the start of the vector instead of the end.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [`drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) to remove multiple contiguous elements from a vector at once as efficiently as possible (the [implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/673d0db5e393e9c64897005b470bfeb6d5aec61b/library/alloc/src/vec/drain.rs#L103) uses `ptr::copy` to move the elements that remain):

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
v.drain(0..2);
assert!(v == vec![3, 4]);
```

Regarding #2, it is not feasible to avoid shifting the remaining elements. That optimization would require changes to the representation of the vector, changes to the allocator, or both, and all for a use case the vector is **not** designed to cover. If you need efficient removal from the front, use a [`VecDeque`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/vec_deque/struct.VecDeque.html).

`Vec` is represented by a triple comprising <[pointer-to-first-element, capacity](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/liballoc/raw_vec.rs#L47-L50), [length](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.16.0/src/libcollections/vec.rs#L296-L299)>. If removal from the front avoided shifting the remaining elements by moving the start pointer forward, deallocation would crash because the start pointer would no longer be the one provided by the allocator. Either the vector would need to get a new field for "original pointer", which would make all vectors pay for the optimization, or the allocation interface would need to be extended with a method for freeing the beginning of a block. *Every* front removal would call into the allocator, which would have performance consequences that are hard to assess, given that the allocator must perform its own bookkeeping and possibly acquire a lock. It would also add burden to the allocator, requiring it to keep track of these potentially tiny unaligned free blocks positioned before the blocks it originally delivered. It would also make vectors incompatible with virtually all native allocators such as `malloc()` and `mmap()`.

Finally, the optimization would contradict the guarantees currently provided by `Vec`. The documentation [explicitly states](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees) that shrinking a `Vec` will not reduce its capacity or deallocate it, unless a call to [`shrink_to_fit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit) is made. This is to avoid excessive allocations for vectors that shrink and grow a lot.

Comment: Thanks, assume this is roughly as efficient as doing (`ptr::drop_in_place`, `ptr::copy`, `Vec::set_len`)

Comment: @ideasman42 That is certainly the intent - see [`impl Drop for Drain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/collections/vec.rs.html#2120) for the details. The compiler is hopefully smart enough to make the fetched and discarded objects in the loop equivalent to `ptr::drop_in_place`, but if in doubt, measure to check if it works for your use case.

Comment: Note: a `VecDeque` does not use contiguous storage (it uses two slices of contiguous storage into a single contiguous buffer; but that's not sufficient for interaction with C).

Answer (score 4):

If you are hell-bent on using a `Vec` directly, then [@user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342) explained why what you are asking for is impossible.

However, if (1) you really need efficient removal from the front and (2) contiguity matters so that `VecDeque` is not appropriate, then it is also possible to build your own container. I once had those (two) stringent requirements in C++, and C++ is much more onerous than Rust in this instance.

The basic structure is:

```
struct DVec<T> {
    data: *mut T,
    length: usize,
    offset: usize,
    capacity: usize,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you can generally shrink the size down by using `u32` in place of `usize` (which still allows 4 billion elements!).

After that, `DVec::drain(..n)` and `DVec::drain(0..n)` are implemented by bumping `offset` by `n`.

This data-structure offers an interface similar to `VecDeque`, with the following changes:

- data is stored contiguously, thus it implements `Deref<Target = [T]>`,
- insertion of an element at either end is **amortized** O(1),
- removal of an element at either end is O(1).

In C++, it is painful to write because not all objects are movable and moves can cause exception; in Rust all objects are movable and moves are exception-free, so it is considerably simpler.

Comment: Did you really intend to link to the user page, or the other answer?

Comment: @Shepmaster: The user page, some users have an annoying habit of changing nicknames, so I prefer to pin them down :)

Comment: But if you link to the answer, it will always be associated to the poster of that answer, regardless of name changes.  If your answer ends up above the other answer, a link to another answer provides an easy way to jump.

Comment: You probably meant `DVec::drain(..n)`. Also, bumping offset is not enough, one must still `drop_in_place` the drained objects. Taking that into account, `drain(..n)` is O(1) if objects don't implement `Drop`, otherwise O(n). But in either case the complexity is not related to the size of the whole vector, which is crucial when you e.g. need to remove a small number of elements from the front of a huge array.

Comment: @user4815162342: Indeed, I made it clear that by O(1) insertions and removal I meant insertion and removal of a single element. This is not a linked list where you can splice things in.

Comment: How would you actually allocate the DVec on the heap, and resize it? I can imagine a hack using `Vec::with_capacity` and `Vec::set_len`, but is there a less hacky way to allocate a boxed slice of an arbitrary length in stable Rust?

Comment: @MichaelHewson: `Vec::with_capacity` gives you a raw buffer, which is exactly what you want. You extract it from the `Vec` using `as_mut_ptr`, `capacity`; and you can rebuild the `Vec` to drop it using `Vec::from_raw_parts`. The rest of the time, you manipulate raw memory because part of it is uninitialized (at both ends).

Comment: I started implementing a DVec data structure like you described. It's really just a proof-of-concept to show myself that this is possible, and it needs a lot more methods and traits to be implemented before it's useful, but if you're interested, [here's the code](https://github.com/mikeyhew/rust-dvec).